# How to combine MySQL data into one table

Tags: mysql, insert

I have 3 tables.

> 1. A users table with just an id and a name.
> 2. A students table with id, name and subject.
> 3. A students_enrolled table which is now empty.

I want find all table entries from 'users' table which have matches in 'students' table.  For this I have the following query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    students
WHERE   name  IN (SELECT name FROM users);

QUERY RESULTS:

id  name
3   mark
4   steve
```

> This works but now the GOAL is to pupulate the third table
>   ('students_enrolled') with this data and have the ids match the users
>   table. In the users table 'mark' is ID 3 and 'steve' is ID 4, but in
>   the students table they are IDs 50 and 99 respectively. I want to
>   insert them into the 'students_enrolled' table with matches IDs to the
>   users table.  *Note: the 'names' will always be unique - there will
>   never be two steves within one table*.

```
The goal is to have the 'students_enrolled' table show this:

id  name    status  subject
3   mark    enrolled    math
4   steve   enrolled    reading
```

I have created a sqlfiddle with all the schema and data if someone has any ideas here:

[sql fiddle link to schema and data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5ea5/1][1]

```
Schema:

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'john'),
    (2, 'jane'),
    (3, 'mark'),
    (4, 'steve');

-- ----------------

CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `students` (`id`, `name`, `subject`)
VALUES
    (50, 'mark', 'math'),
    (99, 'steve', 'reading');


-- ----------------

CREATE TABLE `students_enrolled` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


/* Desired result:*/
/* INSERT INTO `students_enrolled` (`id`, `name`, `status`, `subject`)
VALUES
    (3, 'mark', 'enrolled', 'math'),
    (4, 'steve', 'enrolled', 'reading'); */

-- ----------------
```

> Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [**`INSERT ... SELECT`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) statement to do the insertion:

```
INSERT INTO `students_enrolled` (`id`, `name`, `status`, `subject`)
SELECT u.`id`, s.`name`, 'enrolled', s.`subject`
FROM `students` AS s
INNER JOIN `users` AS u ON s.`name` = u.`name`
```

You can get at `users.id` field using an `INNER JOIN`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4be19/1)

**EDIT:**

You can filter out already existing records in `students_enrolled` table using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO `students_enrolled` (`id`, `name`, `status`, `subject`)
SELECT u.`id`, s.`name`, 'enrolled', s.`subject`
FROM `students` AS s
INNER JOIN `users` AS u ON s.`name` = u.`name`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM `students_enrolled` AS se
                  WHERE se.`id` = u.`id`);
```

Comment: That is really great Giorgos! It works. Much appreciated.  One additional question is why would your query not work one a new user is added to the 'students' table.  For example if you add 'jane' to the student table and run the query, it fails.  It would be great if only jane was added ignoring the existing two users (steve and mark).

Comment: Nevermind! I added the 'INSERT IGNORE' bit to the query and now it works!   Thanks again!

Comment: @ven There is an alternative to using `INSERT IGNORE`. Check the edit I made.

Comment: You are correct. That works even better!  I appreciate your help.